# Java11, what shall MalformedByteSequenceException be replaced with?

Tags: java, java-11, internals, sun

I'm moving a project to Java11

I already changed `sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl` with `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` (as specified [here](https://panlw.github.io/15358753472382.html#fixing-sun-and-com-sun-imports)), now is the turn of `MalformedByteSequenceException`:

> warning: MalformedByteSequenceException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
>   import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException;

it's being use in a snippet of code that create objects from XML files. More precisely in a `try-catch`.

```
    try {
        ...
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(stream);

        NodeList list = document.getChildNodes();

        fillProcessStack(document);
        ...
        list = list.item(0).getChildNodes();
        createItems(list, parent);

    } catch (MalformedByteSequenceException e) {
        //"Any char in your xml file has a wrong format: " + e.getLocalizedMessage()
    } catch (SAXParseException sax) {
        ...
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
```

Anyway I cant find anything online regarding this.

The closest I can think of is `UnsupportedEncodingException`, but I'm not sure.

Also, it's possible this is a relict of some old code copied from the net, and apparently if I remove it everything looks still fine for the compiler.

So, is there any general/good recommendations about it regarding Java11?

Edit: for the guy seeking to close this question because

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

I'll try to be explain clearer.

There is no debugging help here, in Java11 some packages are not exported to public, like `sun.*` and they shouldnt be used normally (unless specific conditions). Code works fine under jdk8, but under ojdk11 it complains, so I could either use some workarounds to make them visible anyway at runtime or make it right and get rid of them. The latter is what I'm trying to do.
Given I couldn't find anything online, I'm asking here.

Comment: What do you mean "being used"? You mean some of your code does new() and throw for that exception type?

Comment: If you remove it from what?

Comment: Are you *catching* this exception at the moment specifically, or explicitly *throwing* it from your code? If you're throwing it, you can presumably throw whatever you like in its place (including a custom exception if you so wish?)

Comment: In a `try-catch`, I modified the question. It's closed source, I'll try to show a shallow copy of that

Comment: 20 seconds with `javap` told me that it extends `java.io.CharConversionException`. I can't really see much reason to catch anything beyond the `IOException` and `SAXException` that are documented for `DocumentBuilder.parse()`.

Comment: @user207421 ok, fine, then I'm leaning toward removal.
You can answer and if nothing else comes up, I'll take that

Comment: 'And then?' What does that mean? Tell us how you've going to treat `CharConversionException` or even `IOException` differently from any other exception and we'll talk. Otherwise there is no question to answer. NB 'they shouldnt be used normally (unless specific conditions)': no; they shoudln't be used at all, period.

Comment: @user207421 'and then' was referred to the previous version of your previous comment. There are some cases, such as accessing raw pointers in the most efficient way, where for example `sun.unsafe` is the most performant way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197044/discussion-between-elect-and-user207421).

Comment: It seems, the behavior of the parser changed anyway. Starting with JDK 11, it doesn’t throw a `MalformedByteSequenceException`, but a `SAXParseException` whose cause is a `MalformedByteSequenceException`. So attempts to catch `MalformedByteSequenceException` will have no effect anyway.

Comment: @Holger, if you want to answer that, I'll take it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MalformedByteSequenceException` extends `CharConversionException`, which extends `IOException`, which the `parse` method forces you to catch anyway. So when catching `IOException` or `CharConversionException`, you’ll also catch `MalformedByteSequenceException` if thrown directly.

However there seems to be a behavioral change of the XML parser in JDK 11. When I try, e.g.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, -5 }));
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:262)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:122)
        at TestXmlParser.main(TestXmlParser.java:14)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:702)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:568)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1904)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1770)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1808)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:158)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:860)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
        ... 3 more
```

instead of the

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(UTF8Reader.java:684)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:554)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1742)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.arrangeCapacity(XMLEntityScanner.java:1619)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipString(XMLEntityScanner.java:1657)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:193)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:232)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
        at TestXmlParser.main(TestXmlParser.java:14)
```

of previous versions.

In other words, `parse` now throws a `SAXParseException` with a cause initialized to a `MalformedByteSequenceException`. So, to detect that the problem is a malformed byte sequence, resp. text in the wrong encoding, you’d need something like

```
catch(SAXException ex) {
    if(ex.getCause() instanceof CharConversionException) {
        System.out.println("maformed bytes or wrong encoding: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To handle newer and older versions, you’d need something like

```
catch(CharConversionException ex) {
    System.out.println("malformed bytes or wrong encoding: "+ex.getMessage());
}
catch(SAXException ex) {
    if(ex.getCause() instanceof CharConversionException) {
        System.out.println("malformed bytes or wrong encoding: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

resp.

```
catch(CharConversionException ex) {
    handle(ex);
}
catch(SAXException ex) {
    if(ex.getCause() instanceof CharConversionException) {
        handle((CharConversionException)ex.getCause());
    }
}

…

static void handle(CharConversionException ex) {
    // just an example
    System.out.println("malformed bytes or wrong encoding: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```